# ":Mi" has no value in the given object

Tags: postgresql

```
select to_date(a.game_date|| ' ' ||a.game_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:Mi') as "beginTime", a.game_id "gameId"
```

one solution is here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7039, which is a good solution.

I am just wondering if there could be another solution to this issue using some escape syntax like `E'foo'`?

I tried using `E'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:Mi'` but didn't work

**Edit:** Adding more details here

I am calling postgres from nodejs not from the terminal. There the issue is not there. It might be related to how string is parsed here. Changing `:` to `||CHR(58)||` works perfectly.

`to_char(to_timestamp(t/1000), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z")` is throwing the error `":Mi" has no value in the given object`

Comment: Why are you using `to_date()` when you are including a time(`a.game_time`) and trying to output a time component? Why not use `to_timestamp()` from here [Formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)?

Comment: My query is not this one ... I took it from the above link ... In mine it is like this `to_char(to_timestamp(t/1000), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z")` which a part of much larger complex query. But that is not the issue right? The point is `:` is treated as replacement .

Comment: Well change the question to address the issue you are having, not someone else's issue. FYI, `select to_date('2022-09-26 7:53', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI'); 09/26/2022` works.

Comment: Added details in the question, my apologies. Actually It is the same issue, that is why :)

Comment: And same solution use `MI` not `Mi`. `select to_char(to_timestamp(1664204637.609392), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS) 2022-09-26 08:03:57`

Comment: kudos to all the effort u r putting in this one, but the issue is something else https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7039#issuecomment-552443941. The question, I am asking, can there be any other escape method? Issue is with `:` being thought as a replacement by sql, even if it is `:MI`

Comment: Then it looks like an encoding issue. What does `show lc_ctype ;` return for the database? What is the locale/encoding the nodejs app is working in?

Comment: don' ask me how :) it's based on hit & trial `E'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24\\:\\MI\\:\\SS"Z"'` this works.